# Am I missing something in the setup project here?

Tags: c#, winforms, enterprise-library, windbg

My .NET/Winform application is using Enterprise Library 5.0 logging block. It works fine on my machine but fails on the QA machine. I have all the necessary DLLs copied in 
the setup project however the application still crashes on the QA machine. I copied all Enterprise Library 5.0 DLLs in the application installation directory but that does not make any difference. Any ideas what could be wrong?

I don't get a stacktrace but when I  attach WinDbg I see following:

```
0:027> !threads  
PDB symbol for mscorwks.dll not loaded  
ThreadCount: 12  
UnstartedThread: 0  
BackgroundThread: 8  
PendingThread: 0  
DeadThread: 2  
Hosted Runtime: no  
                                      PreEmptive   GC Alloc           Lock  
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State     GC       Context       Domain   Count APT Exception  
   0    1 19ec 0085b620      6020 Disabled 12889fd8:12889fe8 008533c8     1 STA (GC)  
   2    2 2af8 008708d0      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 008533c8     0 MTA (Finalizer)  
XXXX    3    0 0728aeb8      5820 Enabled  00000000:00000000 008533c8     0 Ukn  
   8    4 14cc 072c8e30    80a220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 008533c8     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)  
  16    5 13a8 0c5370d8   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 008533c8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)  
  17    6 23d4 00864560   200b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 008533c8     0 MTA  
XXXX    7    0 0c5c3448      9820 Enabled  00000000:00000000 008533c8     0 MTA  
  22    8 2718 0c796e18    80a220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 008533c8     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)  
  24    9 2208 07337c28   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 008533c8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)  
  25    a 16ac 0c563a58   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 008533c8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)  
  26    b  d98 072ce618   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 008533c8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)  
  27    c 2760 0728e170      b022 Disabled 12855dfc:12856290 008533c8     2 MTA System.ExecutionEngineException (025210b4)  
0:027> kb  
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child                
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.  
1074e318 70187125 0728e170 1074e890 00000002 KERNELBASE!DebugBreak+0x2  
1074e7d4 7018735e 80131506 7018858e 00000000 mscorwks!GetAddrOfContractShutoffFlag+0x944f  
1074e7ec 70188599 80131506 7018858e 00000000 mscorwks!GetAddrOfContractShutoffFlag+0x9688  
1074e810 7007693b 1074e890 41f3b57e 0728e170 mscorwks!GetAddrOfContractShutoffFlag+0xa8c3  
1074e844 700767d9 1074e890 41f3b542 1074ea04 mscorwks!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x1855f  
1074e878 6ffdd478 1074e890 00004000 0728e170 mscorwks!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x183fd  
1074e8a4 6ffdd675 1074e9b4 1074f1bc 1074e988 mscorwks!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x9a25  
1074e8c8 77e96ac9 1074e9b4 1074f1bc 1074ea04 mscorwks!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+0x9c22  
1074e8ec 77e96a9b 1074e9b4 1074f1bc 1074ea04 ntdll!RtlDosSearchPath_Ustr+0xada  
1074e99c 77e6010f 0074e9b4 1074ea04 1074e9b4 ntdll!RtlDosSearchPath_Ustr+0xaac  
1074ed8c 6e202eb5 00000000 738b1151 1074eda8 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf  
1074edf4 6e719b9a 6ff6e268 12855de0 73947824 mscorlib_ni+0x1c2eb5  
1074ee10 60fa0148 139077ac 12851b6c 125ecef8 mscorlib_ni+0x6d9b9a  
1074ee24 60f9fc4a 1074f1bc 6ffe0178 ffffffff Microsoft_Practices_EnterpriseLibrary_Logging_ni+0xb0148  
1074ee70 60f9fbe5 60e90585 1074ee8c 60e9074c Microsoft_Practices_EnterpriseLibrary_Logging_ni+0xafc4a  
1074ee7c 60e9074c 1273b864 126a7b70 1074eeb0 Microsoft_Practices_EnterpriseLibrary_Logging_ni+0xafbe5  
1074ee8c 60e9060b 1247ffa4 60ebe938 126a7b70 Microsoft_Practices_EnterpriseLibrary_Common_ni+0x8074c  
1074eeb0 60e8ff01 1074eeec 60e90431 1247ff58 Microsoft_Practices_EnterpriseLibrary_Common_ni+0x8060b  
1074eeb8 60e90431 1247ff58 738c58e2 1247ff58 Microsoft_Practices_EnterpriseLibrary_Common_ni+0x7ff01  
1074eeec 60e9b984 1247ff58 1246dbd4 00000000 Microsoft_Practices_EnterpriseLibrary_Common_ni+0x80431
```

Comment: Your symbols are bad - fix that first and get a new stack trace and paste it here

Comment: Some questions: what is the QA environment vs. Dev environment in terms of OS (32 bit/64 bit)? Is it failing on startup or is it at another point? If it is during startup have you tried using [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to [Debug Obscure Loader Errors](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you app loading properly and then crashing?

If not you are better off running Fusion Log Viewer and see what dlls are failing to load.
copy the fusionlogvw.exe on the qa machine, add `ForceLog` -DWORD value - set to `0x1` under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion` key.

Run the fusionlogvw.exe, and then your application. You should see all assembly bind stats both failure and successes.

This should give an idea as to what dlls aren't loading up.

This [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) and this [one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

make sure both machines are on the same versions of the .NET. try running it on another QA box and see if the problem persists. Currently use EntLib Logging and never seen that error tbh

Comment: @anvardek: both have same version of .NET. Same problem persist on third machine too. Its strange, I have been using EntLib for quite sometime too. Its the first time I see it

Comment: looks like it has created 8 background threads, might be threading issue. hard to see, you can attach debugger to remote machine (make sure you deploy debug build) and then you can see in your Visual Studio where exception is getting thrown. That's what I did when I had problem with app on the server while it was working fine on my box

Comment: In addition to the same "major" version of .NET, make sure you have the same/latest service packs applied on both machines (.NET and Windows).  

Try @anvarek's suggestion with remote debugging if possible.  If QA doesn't want to allow that, see if you can create a VM from the QA machine and try it on the VM.

If that doesn't work I would start comparing installed software and security policies between machines.  For example, are you writing to the event log?  is there some policy in place to prevent that on the QA machine?